# 1 input y un select a 1 misma variable

Tags: php, html

Buenas noches compañeros

Estoy haciendo un formulario para solicitar un codigo o un nombre, para que vaya y busque en una base de datos.
Para hacerlo mas fácil al usuario quisiera darle la opción de que los escriba o los busque en una lista desplegable traida directamente de los datos de la DB
Mi pregunta es.

Es posible que teniendo los campos de ingreso sin la necesidad de hacer 2 formularios ?
La idea es que el que reciba solo el que contenga un valor, pero pasa los 2

agrego el código

```html
<form method='get' action='consulta.php'>
         <input name="equipo" type="text" />
       <select name="equipo">
            <option selected="selected"></option>  
 <?php while($array= mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){?>  
 <option value="<?php echo $array['codigo']?>">   
<?php echo $array['codigo']." | ". $array['nombre']?></option>    <?php }?>   
</select>
        <input type='submit' value='Consultar'>  
 </form> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, no puedes duplicar el atributo `name`, ya que hacen referencia a los datos del formulario después de que se envía un formulario.

> Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo en **PHP**:

```
<form method='POST' action='consulta.php'>
    <input name="equipo" type="text" />
    <select name="equipo_list">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Selecciona un equipo</option>     

        <option value="equipo_1">       
            Equipo 1
        </option>   

        <option value="equipo_2">       
            Equipo 2
        </option>           

    </select>
    <input type='submit' name="consulta" value='Consultar'>     
</form>
```

Veamos como quedaría la página `consulta.php` , luego ya podrás extenderlo a tu gusto o introducir `AJAX` para no recargar la búsqueda.

```
<?php //Pagina consulta

    $reporte = $equipo = $equipo_list = NULL;

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        //Comprobacion si algun campo este vacio.
        if ( empty($_POST['equipo']) && empty($_POST['equipo_list'][0]) ) {

            $reporte = "Error, Debes escribir o seleccionar un 'equipo'";

        } elseif ( !empty($_POST['equipo']) ) { //Obtenemos el dato con el input
            $equipo = $_POST['equipo'];
        } else { //Obtenemos el dato mediante el select
            $equipo_list =  $_POST['equipo_list'];
        }

        if ($equipo) {

            //Hacemos algo con $euipo
            echo "OK equipo";

        }

        if ($equipo_list) {

            //Hacemos algo con $equipo_list
            echo "OK equipo_list";

        }
    }

    //MSG errores.
    echo $reporte;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del formulario, no puede haber varios campos que tengan el mismo nombre. El input y el select deben tener nombres diferentes porque es lo que php utiliza para identificar uno del otro cuando realizas la peticion GET al servidor que estas utilizando.

Comment: Ok pero hay alguna forma de validarle que si está vació no lo envie, asi solo toma 1

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es agregar la propiedad "required" en el input para que el usuario tenga que rellenar el dato de forma obligatoria y asi te evitas todo eso.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás podrías hacerlo con *Javascript*, primero removerías el atributo `name` del `input` y `select`, y lo agregarias mediante javascript al hacer `submit` del formulario.

Algo como por ejemplo:

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('TeamForm');
var inputTeam = document.getElementById('InputTeam');
var selectTeam = document.getElementById('SelectTeam');

myForm.addEventListener('submit',function(){

    if(inputTeam.value != '')
    {
        inputTeam.setAttribute('name','team');
        selectTeam.removeAttribute('name');
        console.log(inputTeam);
        console.log(selectTeam);
    }
    else if(selectTeam.value != 0)
    {
          selectTeam.setAttribute('name','team');
          inputTeam.removeAttribute('name');
          console.log(inputTeam);
          console.log(selectTeam);
    }
    else
    {return false;}
      
    // Send to action
  
},false);
```

```html
<form method="GET" id="TeamForm">

    <input id="InputTeam" type="text" />
    <select id="SelectTeam">
      <option value="0">Select a team</option>
      <option value="1">Team 1</option>
      <option value="2">Team 2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Así conseguirías enviar solo un elemento con el atributo `name`, y al final ingresarías el código para enviar los datos a tu acción en *PHP*. Podrías hacerlo mediante *AJAX*.

Si revisas la consola, [aquí](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqZYOY) verás que sólo un elemento es enviado con  el atributo `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes ya pude dar una solución tomando como referencia el código que me envió D Bulten.
Lo que hice fué validar por donde estaban enviando el dato antes de enviarlo a la consulta y así enviar solo uno

```html
<form action="" method='post'>
    <input type='text' name="equipo" />
 <select name="equipo_list" >
            <option selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="equipo1">equipo1</option>
   <option value="equipo1">equipo2</option>
   </select>
  <input type='submit' value='Consultar' name="consultar"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['consultar'])) {
 //Comprobacion si algun campo este vacio.
        if ( empty($_POST['equipo']) and empty($_POST['equipo_list']) ) {
     echo "Debe seleccionar uno de los campos";
   } elseif ( !empty($_POST['equipo']) ) { //Obtenemos el dato con el input
            $equipo = $_POST['equipo'];
   header('location: consulta.php?equipo='.$equipo);
        } else { //Obtenemos el dato mediante el select
            $equipo =  $_POST['equipo_list'];
   header('location: consulta.php?equipo='.$equipo);

        }
 }
 ?>
```